# Connecting to postgresql by R using connecting string

Tags: r, postgresql

I would like to connect to postgresql database by R using connecting string.
So far I used the standard method, where I separately define the user, password, server, etc.
However, attempts to connect using the connecting string end in failure.

When I use:

```
  dbConnect(
    RPostgres::Postgres(),
    host = "test_server_address",
    port = 12345,
    dbname = "test_db_name",
    user = "test_user",
    password = "test_password"
  )
```

It works fine, connection has been established, but when I use:

```
dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), .connection_string = "Uid=test_user;Pwd=test_password;Host=test_server_address;Port=12345;Database=test_db_name;")
```

I get error: `Error: invalid connection option ".connection_string"`

How to repair code which contain connection string to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PqDriver` method for `DBI::dbConnect` does not support a `.connection_string` parameter. Check out `?dbConnect` and click on the PqDriver method to see details about what is and isn't supported. The only documentation I've been able to find for connection strings with RPostgres is negatively expressed (i.e. it documents arguments where they are **not** supported).

I suppose one option would be to parse your connection string into a list of arguments and then call dbConnect with do.call, e.g.

```
my_string <- "Uid=test_user;Pwd=test_password;Host=test_server_address;Port=12345;Database=test_db_name;"

args <- strsplit(strsplit(my_string, ";")[[1]], "=")

vals <- lapply(args, `[`, 2)

names(vals) <- lapply(args, `[`, 1)

do.call(dbConnect, c(RPostgres::Postgres(), vals))
```

You may need to rename `vals`.